# How can I solve a TypeError when deploying my Bot to Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py

I tried to create a bot that plays music. After deploying it to Heroku I get the following **error**:

```py
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: _hook() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I tried to host the bot from my computer and it works fine. However it's not working when I am trying to host it on Heroku.

**Here is my code:**

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['j', 'joi'])
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()

    await voice.disconnect()

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        await channel.connect()
        print(f"The bot has connected to {channel}\n")

    await ctx.send(f"Joined {channel}")
```

Comment: Please share the code!

Comment: The error includes something about `_hook()`, but the code doesn't seem to have this. Are you sure you have shared the right code with us?

Comment: Yes, this was the code, there is nothing like _hook()

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is not the best host if you are looking to deploy a Music Discord Bot, especially when you use FFMPEG. While there is a way, it takes a lot of work to implement. I recommend using a VPN such as Vultr, if you don't want to play you can use PenguinBots, or ShockNodes.